# Is there anyway to reduce bandwidth usage of Skype for business?

Tags: skype, compression, bandwidth, skype-for-business

We use a lot of 'Skype for Business' (i.e. the new Microsoft Lync), that I use while consuming expensive roaming data. Was wondering, if there are options (similar to various VLC clients) that lead to lower consumption of data, by dropping the audio quality (lower bit-rate), and similarly the quality of desktop-sharing video (again, resort to scaling-down, compression, lower bit-rate codec etc.) ?